A Geometry Problem from BDMO 2023
 is a convex quadrilateral such that ∠ = ∠,  =  and  ≠ . Prove that
 is cyclic.
(A convex quadrilateral is a quadrilateral having all of its interior angles measuring less than °.
A convex quadrilateral is cyclic if and only if the sum of its two opposite angles is °.)
Please help me to solve. I have tried triangular inequality and some extensions,but this doesn't work well.I am preparing for BDMO 2025 and want to solve this problem.
source:BDMO National 2023 2nd question.

Here is an outline: The angle bisector of $\angle B$ and the perpendicular bisector of $[AC]$ intersect at one unique point (because they are different lines due to $|AB| \neq |BC|$), and this point is $D$ given in the problem. On the other hand, the intersection of the angle bisector of $\angle B$ with the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ (call it $D'$) satisfies $|D'B| = |D'C|$, which means that $D'$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $[AC]$ too. This shows that $D'$ is the unique point mentioned above, i.e., $D' = D$. Therefore, $ABCD$ is cyclic.

$ABCD$ being a convex quadrilateral means all internal angles are $\le 180^{\circ}$. If either of $\measuredangle DAB$ and $\measuredangle DCB$ is $180^{\circ}$, then $\measuredangle ABD = \measuredangle DBC = 0^{\circ}$. This means that $ABCD$ would be a degenerate quadrilateral, where it would be composed of just one line, with $\lvert AB\rvert = \lvert BC\rvert$, which is not allowed. In general, any of the internal angles being $0^{\circ}$ or $180^{\circ}$ means $\lvert AB\rvert = \lvert BC\rvert$, so this isn't permitted.
The following diagram illustrates the problem conditions:

Using the law of sines with $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle CBD$ gives
$$\frac{\lvert AD\rvert}{\sin(\measuredangle ABD)} = \frac{\lvert BD\rvert}{\sin(\measuredangle DAB)}, \;\; \frac{\lvert CD\rvert}{\sin(\measuredangle DBC)} = \frac{\lvert BD\rvert}{\sin(\measuredangle DCB)}$$
Since it's given that $\lvert AD\rvert = \lvert CD\rvert$ and $\measuredangle ABD = \measuredangle DBC$, the LHS of the above $2$ equations are equal, so their RHS's must also be equal. Thus,
$$\frac{\lvert BD\rvert}{\sin(\measuredangle DAB)} = \frac{\lvert BD\rvert}{\sin(\measuredangle DCB)} \;\;\to\;\; \sin(\measuredangle DAB) = \sin(\measuredangle DCB)$$
With both angles being $\gt 0^{\circ}$ and $\lt 180^{\circ}$, as explained initially, then $\measuredangle DAB$ and $\measuredangle DCB$ must either be equal to each other or be supplementary angles. If they were equal, then due to the sum of angles in triangles always being $180^{\circ}$, we would also have that $\measuredangle ADB = \measuredangle CDB$. Thus, since $DB$ is a common side, we get
$$\triangle ADB \cong \triangle CDB \;\;\to\;\; \lvert AB\rvert = \lvert BC\rvert$$
However, it's given that $\lvert AB\rvert \neq \lvert BC\rvert$. This means that $\measuredangle DAB$ and $\measuredangle DCB$ are supplementary instead, i.e., they sum to $180^{\circ}$. Thus, since the angles in a quadrilateral sum to $360^{\circ}$, the other $2$ opposite angles must also have a sum of $180^{\circ}$. As such, as you've already noted, this shows that $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

By sine rule, the circumradius of $ABD$ and $BCD$ are equal since $ \frac{|AD|}{\sin \angle ABD } = \frac{|CD|} { \sin \angle DBC} = d$.
Consider all possible circles of that diameter $d$ with $BC$ as a chord. There are only 2 such circles, which are reflections of each other about $BD$. Let's denote them as $ \Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$.
Consider the circle $\Gamma_3$ centered at $D$ with radius $| AD|$.
$\Gamma_3$ intersects $\Gamma_1$ (resp $\Gamma_2$) in at most 2 points, on either side of $BD$. Label these $1_x, 1_y$ (resp $2_x, 2_y$, which are corresponding reflections about $BD$).
WLOG $A = 1_x$.
Since $ABCD$ is convex, and $1_x, 2_y$ are on the same side of $BD$, hence $ C \neq 2_y$.
Since $2_x$ is a reflection of $1_x$ about $BD$, the condition $AB \neq BC$ means $C \neq 2_x$.
Thus, $ C = 1_y$, so $A, B, C, D$ are concyclic on the same circle.

Here's as simple of a solution as I could find using purely geometry.

1.) Map $\triangle ABD$ "into" $\triangle BDC$ by reflecting $A$ onto segment $BC$ to $E$. The resulting shape $AECD$ is a sector of a circle. Note that $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle ADE$ are isosceles where $BD$ is an angle bisector, this implies that $\triangle AEF$ is isosceles as well.
2.) Labeling $\angle FEA=FAE=\theta$, we get $\angle EFC=EDC=2\theta$, implying that quadrilateral $FECD$ is cyclic. It's obvious that $\angle DEC=90-\theta$ here, and we know $\angle FEA=\theta$, this implies that $\angle FED+\angle BEA$ must be $90^\circ$. Since $\angle BEA=90-\alpha$, this only means that $\angle FED=\alpha$.
3.) Due to quadrilateral $FEDC$ being cyclic as established earlier, this makes $\angle FCD=\alpha$ and consequently $\angle FAD=\alpha$ as well. However this is only true if $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, and that completes this proof.

IMO You should clarify how you used the condition that $AB \neq BC$, since  without it we need not have $ABCD$ conyclic.

@CalvinLin Yes that's what I had meant, I worded it incorrectly, I'll fix it. And as for the section, I meant to write "sector", I wasn't doing all this on a phone and made several mistakes. As for $AB \neq BC$, that's already a given in the problem statement so it would've been redundant for me to go over that case.

I disagree that it's redundant. There is an important place where you implicitly use the condition that $AB \neq BC$, in order to draw the correct conclusion.  With geometry diagrams, one has to be careful that the drawing may not reflect all possible configurations as described by the conditions, eg like assuming a point is inside/outside a figure.

I mean, it is rather obvious that $E$ lies on the "inside" segment $BC$, because $AB \neq BC$ (more specifcally. $AB < BC$ here). If they were equal, this construction makes little sense. Is that really a noteworthy detail though? I don't mind adding it if you think it'll help other viewers.

IMO It is worth mentioning because that's how you used the condition (and that the statement isn't true without that condition). IE If $ E = C$, then $FEDC$ is trivially cyclic, so where does your proof break down as $ABCD$ need not be cyclic?

Well, if $E$ lies in $C$, then quadrilateral $FEDC$ just becomes $\triangle FED$ which is trivially cyclic as you said. If that happens, quadrilateral $ABCD$ becomes a kite which cannot really be cyclic unless at least two of its opposite angles are $90^\circ$. Is that a good enough justification to edit into the answer?

To me that does not justify where your proof breaks down (but merely substantiates that it breaks down), though someone else might disagree. I leave it up to you to decide how you want to present it.

That's easy to see too. If the opposing angles aren't $90^\circ$ then this is a non-cyclic Kite/Quadrilateral, but the moment that $AB \neq BC$, my proof shows up in that case.
